# Spring Authorization Server 1.2.1 does not forward anonymous /authorize call to the login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm in the process of upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.1 / Security 6, and the OAuth refactoring is just .. let's say, rather tedious. I'm trying to get the Spring Authorization Server (1.2.1) to work, using https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html as a guideline. Yet, when I anonymously navigate to the /oauth2/authorize endpoint, I'm not forwarded to the login page. Instead, the response is just a 401 Unauthorized.

In the logs I see

```
2024-01-15T17:01:18.524Z DEBUG 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=foobar&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/public/login&state=foobar&scope=read+write
2024-01-15T17:01:18.528Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.541Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.547Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.550Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationServerContextFilter (4/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.553Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (5/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.558Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (6/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.562Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1317/0x0000000801921d20@3627bfdd]]]
2024-01-15T17:01:18.563Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (7/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.563Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2024-01-15T17:01:18.563Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (8/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.563Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (9/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.567Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2024-01-15T17:01:18.567Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-01-15T17:01:18.567Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-01-15T17:01:18.584Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider (1/15)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.758Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] izationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider : Retrieved registered client
2024-01-15T17:01:18.781Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] izationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider : Validated authorization code request parameters
2024-01-15T17:01:18.781Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] izationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider : Did not authenticate authorization code request since principal not authenticated
2024-01-15T17:01:18.784Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter (10/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.784Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter (11/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.784Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter (12/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.784Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (13/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.785Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-01-15T17:01:18.785Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (14/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.788Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (15/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.789Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (16/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.789Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (17/21)
2024-01-15T17:01:18.793Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@16800744]
2024-01-15T17:01:18.794Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@16800744] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@5095293a
2024-01-15T17:01:18.794Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-01-15T17:01:18.803Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationServerContextFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

2024-01-15T17:01:18.836Z DEBUG 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8081/funnel-server/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=funnelwebclient&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/public/login&state=TODO&scope=read+write&continue to session
2024-01-15T17:01:18.837Z TRACE 21784 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
```

My understanding is that /oauth2/authorize should be protected by the default SecurityFilterChain, requiring an authenticated user. (At least that's how I read the manual's setup). I have

```
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }
}
```

and then

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(customizer -> {
                customizer.loginPage("/login");
            })
            .build();
    }
}
```

and yet somewhere there's a stupid little mistake. Where?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to the sample at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http
            .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))
            .oauth2ResourceServer(customizer -> {
                customizer.jwt(jwtCustomizer -> {
                    // TODO: need to check why a resource server call should be on an auth server config?? 
                });
            });
        return http
            .build();
    }
}
```

with the key points:

1. Don't @Import OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration when defining own SecurityFilterChain
2. Define exceptionHandling() pointing to LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint

** EDIT Jan 17th 2024 **

Compare the Spring Security configuration

```
package org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration;

public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.build();
    }
    ...
}
```

versus the Spring Boot configuration

```
package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.server.servlet;

class OAuth2AuthorizationServerWebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(withDefaults());
        http.oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()));
        http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), createRequestMatcher()));
        return http.build();
    }
    ...
}
```

The latter defines a default AuthenticationEntryPoint, with a media type restriction on accept = text/html. The OAuth2AuthorizationServerWebSecurityConfiguration#authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain seems like a good starting point for a configuration.